# how to create a remote mysql table by federate?

Tags: mysql, federated-table

I have read this [federate TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-create-connection.html) and now I would like to know what to do if I want to create the `test_table` (see this example in the link) from remote?
As I do understand that `test_table` must be created on the federate server before. But I would like to create this by doing so from  my local server.

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to create a minimal version of the remote table by my own manually and let `alter table tablename add columnname` run. Now I get this error. (The Fields is ACA.PA in table levermanneasypivot.)

```
   Field:  ACA.PA does not exists
   Error at: Do an alter ADD COLUMN  ACA.PA @ easy
   Error at: cmd: alter table `levermanneasypivot` add ` ACA.PA` int(9) 
   default NULL;
   Errormsg: cmd: Table storage engine for 'levermanneasypivot' doesn't have this option
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, as described in [15.9.3 FEDERATED Storage Engine Notes and Tips](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-usagenotes.html):

> The following items indicate features that the `FEDERATED` storage engine does and does not support:
>
> - The remote table that a `FEDERATED` table points to *must* exist before you try to access the table through the `FEDERATED` table.

You can use the [`connect`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html#idm140718728032976) command to connect to a remote server from inside the `mysql` client. But then, you could just connect to the remote server with `mysql -h remote_addr` directly.

Comment: Thanks yes I will make a script call with that mysql call and pipe the create or alter add column line into it